# Swift 4.2/5. get 'key' of number in array that is assigned to this key in Dictionary

Tags: swift

My code actually works but i need to print the secondLargest key that is assigned to the array the number (16 - which is the second largest) is contained.
How can I access this key?

```
let interestingNumbers = ["prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13], "fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8], "square": [1,4,9,16,25]]

var largest = 0;
var secondLargest=0

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers{
    for number in numbers {
        if number>largest {
            secondLargest = largest
            largest = number
        } else if (number > secondLargest && number != largest) {
            secondLargest=number
        }
    }
}
print( "The largest number is: \(largest) ")
print( "The second largest number is: \(secondLargest) and is a\(kind) 
kind ")
```

Comment: What happens when the second largest number is there in multiple arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You may go With Tuples

```
let interestingNumbers = ["prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13], "fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8], "square": [1,4,9,16,25]]

var largest:(key:String, number:Int) = ("",0);
var secondLargest:(key:String, number:Int) = ("",0)

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers{
    for number in numbers {
        if number>largest.number {
            secondLargest = (kind,largest)
            largest = (kind, number)
        } else if (number > secondLargest.number && number != largest.number) {
            secondLargest= (kind,number)
        }
    }
}
print( "The largest number is: \(largest.number) ")
print( "The second largest number is: \(secondLargest.number) and is a\(secondLargest.key) 
kind ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functional solution:

1. Map each array into an array of (key, value) tuples
2. Flatten the resulting array of arrays into a single array of (key, value) tuples
3. Sort the list by each tuple's value
4. Drop the largest item
5. The second largest item is now the last item

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

let interestingNumbers = ["prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13], "fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8], "square": [1,4,9,16,25]]

if let secondLargest = interestingNumbers
    .map({key, value in
        value.map { (key, $0) }
    })
    .flatMap({$0})
    .sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0})
    .dropLast()
    .last {
        print(secondLargest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to sort all numbers in one array as tuples with their kind. Then you can get any number of largest numbers and their kind

```swift
let sortedInteresting = interestingNumbers.map { (arg: (key: String, value: [Int])) -> ([(String,Int)]) in
    let (key, value) = arg
    return value.map { (key, $0) }
}
.flatMap{ $0 }
.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }

largest = sortedInteresting.first!.1
secondLargest = sortedInteresting.dropFirst().first!.1
key = sortedInteresting.dropFirst().first!.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `forEach` and `max`/`max(by:)`

```
var largest = 0;
var secondLargest=0
var savedKind = ""
interestingNumbers.forEach { 
    if let max = $0.value.max() {
       if max > largest { largest = max }
       let next = $0.value.max(by: { $0 < $1 && $1 < max }) ?? -1
       if next > secondLargest {
           secondLargest = next
           savedKind = $0.key
       }
    }
}

print( "The largest number is: \(largest) ")
print( "The second largest number is: \(secondLargest) and is a \(savedKind) kind ")
```